# Design pattern to encapsulate generation of columns of tabular data?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Consider the following situation:

A CSV file gets generated from some data with lines like this:

> 011111;1;1000221;014501;100;343;0;0;0,085;8,5;0;0;0,075;7,5;0;0;0;0

There's a lot more fields and fields are added every once in a while.
The code generating each line is a function of 240 lines.

Now I want to refactor this code in a way that each column will get its own object with it's own logic encapsulated in every object. It would make adding new columns easier and the code more readable.

But what pattern to use here? Composite or Decorator?

Decorator because there's a basic line already and it could get "decorated" with extra columns.
And composite because every line is "composed" of all columns.

What would be a better choice?

Comment: why don't you use just a collection of the `column objects`, that will be written sequentially without this patterns?

Comment: Questions about selecting an appropriate design are generally a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ than StackOverflow (which is focused on code, not design).

Answer (score 1):

If your columns have complex logic for evaluating and you wan't to accord to SOLID principles (especially the Open/Closed Principle) you could make a base class or interface for your columns, with an "EvaluateValue" method. Than you are able to add new columns by deriving new classes, without changing the existing code. Only the initializer that instantiates all columns must be extended by a new line (appending the new column) but this is less error prone than adding something in 240 lines of code. You could use some IoC/DI Container to create all Column instances as well to avoid this.